# Why linux ld somtime use the symbolic link of libs

Tags: c++, linux, ld

I use the jsoncpp lib in my linux cli tool.

The CMakeLists.txt contains

```
find_library(LIB_JSON jsoncpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${LIB_JSON})
```

The result is

```
/usr/bin/c++ -rdynamic CMakeFiles/cktwagent.dir/agent_main.cpp.o -o cktwagent -ljsoncpp
```

When i check the binary I found:

```
 $> ldd cktwagent 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe4cfd1000)
    libjsoncpp.so.24 => /usr/lib/libjsoncpp.so.24 (0x00007f87505bd000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f87503e0000)
    libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007f875029a000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f8750280000)
    libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f87500b7000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f87506ce000)
```

Why ld use /usr/lib/libjsoncpp.so.24 and not the symbolic link /usr/lib/libjsoncpp.so?

Why the ld sometime resolv the linbrary link to the real library file?

```
$> ls -l /usr/lib/libjsoncpp.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 26. Sep 17:02 /usr/lib/libjsoncpp.so -> libjsoncpp.so.24
```

In case of /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 the ld use the symbolic link. When i check the path from ldd output, libstdc++.so.6 point to a symbolic link.

```
$> ls -l /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19  9. Nov 12:43 /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.28
```

I like to understand this behavior. Because when i copy the binary to a different system, the link to libjsoncpp.so available. But it points to some different version.

Many thanks

Thomas

Comment: The symbolic links have to do with ABI versioning, as described in [How To Write Shared Libraries section 3.3](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a version compatibility feature. By convention, API compatibility is determined by the major version number. So `6.0.28` would be is compatible with `6.1.1`, but not with `5.0.1` or `7.0.1`.

To allow for compatible upgrades, `libstdc++.so.6.0.28` is symlinked as `libstdc++.so.6`. Then it can be binary-upgraded to e.g. `libstdc++.so.6.0.29` without touching applications that rely on API version `6` of `libstdc++`.

In addition, it allows libraries with different major version numbers to coexist on the same system. Installing `libstdc++.so.7.0.0` will not break apps that link against `libstdc++.so.6`.

> *Why ld use `/usr/lib/libjsoncpp.so.24` and not the symbolic link `/usr/lib/libjsoncpp.so`?*

That's because `libjsoncpp` has a ***soname*** of `libjsoncpp.so.24`. Apparently it is following the same convention of having the major version number determine compatibility.

You can achieve the same behavior with your shared lib `libfoo` if you link it like this:

```
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libfoo.so.<major> -o libfoo.so.<major>.<minor>
```

For more details refer to [GCC Howto -  Version numbering, sonames and symlinks](http://netwinder.osuosl.org/pub/netwinder/docs/misc/GCC-HOWTO-html/GCC-HOWTO-6.html#index.74).